# How do I add ‘google-services.json’ file to a Meteor/Cordova project?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I'm trying to add a 'google-services.json' file to the Cordova project root folder as required by the cordova-plugin-fcm plugin (this plugin allows a receiving push notifications from Google Firebase). But because I'm using Meteor, the project root folder is not the same as the cordova root folder.
I've tried adding the file to both:

`/<meteor project root>/cordova-build-override/google-services.json
/<meteor project root>/cordova-build-override/platforms/android/google-services.json`

However I still receive the following error:
`While adding plugin cordova-plugin-fcm@2.1.1 to Cordova project:
Error: cordova-plugin-fcm: You have installed platform android but file
'google-services.json' was not found in your Cordova project root
folder.`
Its initiated by this file: https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/blob/master/scripts/fcm_config_files_process.js#L842

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug with the 2.1.1 version of cordova-plugin-fcm https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/212.

I installed a different firebase plugin, cordova-plugin-firebase with my google-services.json file located at:
`/<meteor project root>/cordova-build-override/google-services.json`

and everything is now working as expected.